# How Android linear layout orientation affects layout gravity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have LinearLayout (video button container) and image button as it's child. I want that video button to be right aligned, so I gave it `layout_gravity="right"`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!-- VIDEO BUTTON CONTAINER -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="top">

        <!-- VIDEO BUTTON -->
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/controls_button_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/controls_button_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_video" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- some FrameLayout and another LinearLayout -->
</LinearLayout>
```

It produces this:

[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

And I get that by changing video button container's`android:orientation="horizontal"` to `android:orientation="vertical"`.
What happened? Why it doesn't work with container's horizontal orientation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the container is horizontal, then it is supposed to stack elements from left to right in order. Now, if that's the case, how can it satisfy a layout gravity horizontally while keeping its original premise?

A horizontal gravity (right, left, center) will work in a vertical LinearLayout and a vertical gravity (top, bottom) will work in a horizontal LinearLayout.

Comment: Hi! What does the orientation attribute do though? I didn't see any difference in my layout when I went from `vertical` to `horizontal`...Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just put

> gravity="right"

into the horizontal linear layout, it should do the trick :)

Works well in my case (just an exemple based on your layout):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!-- VIDEO BUTTON CONTAINER -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:gravity="right">

        <!-- VIDEO BUTTON -->
        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button_video"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- some FrameLayout and another LinearLayout -->
</LinearLayout>
```

**-- Edit --**

About the orientation of a LinearLayout: vertical and horizontal allows to define which way will the children inside the layout will be placed next to each other, horizontally or vertically.

The gravity property allows you to control the anchor of the layout which in your case should be at the right of the Layout.

Comment: That adjusts the content inside the `View`...not the `View` inside its parent